# Abstract Algebra: Struggles with rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

[image]

This is a part of the group of practice problem I've been working on and I'm just lost. I'm really struggling when it comes to these ring problems. Anybody who could lay out an outline for this problem so I can study the structure to help with other problems?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If your matrix has $a,b,c,d$ entries. Then you need that $ac-bd\neq0$ in order for your matrix to be invertible. How many ways can you do this?

Comment: I suppose any time that ac does not equal bd

Comment: Well you know you only have two choices for each letter right? So if $a=c=1$ then that forces $b=d=0$. Similarly, if $a=0=c$ then $b=d=1$. Then take care of all the other cases. This is just one to start you with.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with $\Bbb Z_2$? It has two elements, the $0$ (corresponding to the even numbers) and the $1$ (corresponding to the odd numbers).

How many $2\times 2$ matrix can be made using only these $2$ elements as entries?

> $2^4$

Can you just count those which are invertible matrices? (Help: now such a matrix is non invertible iff it either contains a $0$ row or column or is $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$.)